# blender 2.78 problem with bridge edge loop

Tags: modeling

When cutting a hole in the plane, I got into this problem.

v. 2.78
[image]

In the previous version of the blender (2.7), this problem does not exist.

v. 2.77
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It appears to me that if you select all of the vertices of the hole you are trying to cut, and rotate them 180 degrees on the y (green) axis, you will solve your problem.